# Does the server need to know the client is using jsonp?

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp

We have a existing server which receives POST data and respond with json. The server is using Django. I am developing an webpage game using the json data. However I figured out I may need to use jsonp because the game is hosted on another domain. I want to know if the server need to know I am using jsonp (i.e. does the server need to change the code) or it is completely transparent to the server side? I cannot reach the server developer so I hope I can get advise here. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, server must respond differently - [JSNOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) requires that JSON response is wrapped in some sort of function call.

```
wrapperFunc({"Name": "Foo", "Id": 1234, "Rank": 7});
```

Note that securing JSONP against [Cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) is harder than using proper [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) which you may be able to use if you don't need to target old versions of IE.